# Finder shortcut for new TAB

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

I thought <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> was for new tab in finder but it keeps opening Terminal instead.

How can I activate a new Tab in Finder with keyboard shortcut ?

Comment: Does it open/run Terminal.app or just create a new tab for an already running Terminal.app?

Comment: On my system, looking at **Finder** > **File** > **New Tab**, it's shows **⌘T** and it does indeed open a new tab when **Finder** has focus.  If it's not doing the same for you, then you must have changed something some where. Maybe somewhere in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **...**

Comment: @nohillside it launches Terminal

Comment: @user3439894 im working from a brand new install of Mavericks, so everything is default. There are no assignments for command T there

Comment: Can you please create a new user account, log in as that user and press Cmd-T there (without running Terminal first)?

Comment: Doing a clean install of OS X Mavericks from the US App Store with US English settings... Looking at **Finder** > **File** > **New Tab**, it's shows **⌘T** and it does indeed open a new tab when **Finder** has focus and a window is already open. If no Finder window is open, it opens a new window. Also looking at the usual places in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **...** there is nothing that has a setting of **⌘T**, nor does pressing **⌘T** open **Terminal** when it is closed.

Comment: If **Terminal** is open and and has focus, with an opened window, it does create a new tab as expected and exhibits the same behavior as when **Finder** has focus. That said, since the behavior I've described is the default behavior for OS X Mavericks downloaded from the App Store, where did you acquire the copy of OS X Mavericks? If anywhere other the a valid Apple source, like the IT Department where you work if applicable, I'd contact them. Otherwise, IMO the installer you used has been modified and I personally wouldn't use it.